# Best UI Practices to show Multi-Action Button while avoiding tabular layout

Tags: usability, buttons, tables

We have a screen which was given to us by a client. As per their module, when the user selects a tab, the page should show options to do certain tasks like create/edit/delete.

One approach we went for is to show Label & buttons of the Action in the tabular format. While implementing it we faced some User Experience issues in the mobile screen as a table is not feasible for every screen for just a two-column layout. Also, a few labels leave a lot of white space on the page. What approach should we go for with this kind of layout?

Image for the current layout wireframe:

[image]

Comment: I suggest making the resulting question more concrete. Like "our goal is to show user many options per item on a small screen. What patterns exist solving this specific need?"

Comment: I'm wondering if some of the older questions and answers on this site could help you, e.g. search for "large table mobile"?

Answer (score 1):

A better way to group the actions would be to have 3 vertical or horizontal dots for all the actions as shown in the screenshot below. I assume you have used dummy text for the actions, BUT despite that I would definitely urge you to consider which actions are specific to a table row.

- Perhaps it is not a good idea to have a 'View' action as that can definitely be achieved by clicking on the row.
- If 'Create' is also an action, then it is definitely for the whole table v/s for each row.

A good read on UX StackExchange: [What is the difference between the horizontal three dots menu and the vertical one?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/95566/135510))

[image: Action column in a table with horizontal dots]

Comment: Good Idea but It only follows in the table type layout. tablink is not table header, it's just tab buttons to switch between different forms.example : [link](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_tabs&stacked=h)

Comment: "View" Considers in action according to client as user group will be 40-60 Age Group were they unable to find click on a row & All Action should be clearly visible.