# Should I use kebab or meatball menu in desktop?

Tags: menu

Is there a "rule" or "design consensus" regarding the use of kebab or meatball menu in desktop design? I want to use kebab menu because it looks better than meatball but want to make sure it would be ok.

[image: Examples of kebab and meatball menus]

Comment: I'm not aware of any "rule" or formal consensus, but you may find the discussion at https://www.reddit.com/r/Design/comments/8856ft/from_an_ux_standpoint_what_are_the_different/ enlightening.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/95566/what-is-the-difference-between-the-horizontal-three-dots-menu-and-the-vertical-o

Answer (score 2):

The hamburger menu and all its derivatives have been created to optimize spaces in reduced visibility fields of mobile devices. Then they have been adapted to desktop according to:

- Functionality: toolbar extension, almost always as an extra addition
- Aesthetics: reduce the number of elements on the screen,
  avoid long menu listing, etc.

If the case of the question is the first point:

- The three vertical dots are useful on horizontal bars such as the settings menu of Chrome [image]
- The three horizontal dots on vertical toolbars, such as some app toolbars like Facebook or Illustrator, or following any horizontal element like the tweet top line on Twitter.

| [image] | [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| *Facebook* | *Illustrator* | *Twitter* |

If it's the aesthetic case, any option is valid, aesthetics totally lacks consensus. I would only take care it has a correct visualization.